# How to create an Index in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create indexes in Amazon Redshift but I received an error

```
create index on session_log(UserId);
```

`UserId` is an integer field.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you try and create an index (with a name) on a Redshift table:

```
create index IX1 on "SomeTable"("UserId");
```

You'll receive the error

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>   create index IX1 on "SomeTable"("UserId")
>   ERROR: SQL command "create index IX1 on "SomeTable"("UserId")" not supported on Redshift tables.

This is because, like other [data warehouses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS), Redshift uses [columnar storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_columnar_storage_disk_mem_mgmnt.html), and as a result, many of the indexing techniques (like adding non-clustered indexes) used in other RDBMS aren't applicable.

You do however have the option of providing a single [sort key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html) per table, and you can also influence performance with a [distribution key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html) for sharding your data, and selecting appropriate [compression encodings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-tuning-tables.html) for each column to minimize storage and I/O overheads.

For example, in your case, you may elect to use `UserId` as a sort key:

```
create table if not exists "SomeTable"
(
    "UserId" int,
    "Name" text
)
sortkey("UserId");
```

You might want to read a few primers [like](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift_system_overview.html) [these](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/)

Comment: broken: "like these"

Comment: @Faiz Thanks - I've updated, although I can't really find a good 'mindshift' reference on AWS for those who are used to more traditional Sql databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can [Define Constraints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html) but will be informational only, as Amazon says: they are not enforced by Amazon Redshift. Nonetheless, primary keys and foreign keys are used as planning hints and they should be declared if your ETL process or some other process in your application enforces their integrity.

Some services like pipelines with insert mode (REPLACE_EXISTING) will need a primary key defined in your table.

For other performance purposes the Stuart's response is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift allow to create primary key

```
create table user (
id int ,
phone_number int,
primary key(id))
```

but since Redshift does not enforce this constraints, primary key accepts duplicate values.

attached article on that issue

> http://www.sqlhaven.com/amazon-redshift-what-you-need-to-think-before-defining-primary-key/

Comment: The question asks specifically for creating an "index" and not "primary key".