# Primary key without duplicated values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i'm trying and success to create primary key in Redshif

```
   create table my_table(id int ,
    primary key(id));


insert into my_table values
(id),
(1),
(1),
(20);

select count(*) from my_table

3
```

but it allows me to upload duplicated value ,

as far as i know primary key should contain unique values ,

did i do something wrong?

Comment: Can you show a full snippet of that works (although it's supposed to fail)? A primary key should indeed prohibit duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find your answer here

> [How to create an Index in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088161/how-to-create-an-index-in-amazon-redshift)

one of the answers mention your problem with the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Create an `identity key` which will act as an auto_increment surrogate key. This'll serve both the purpose - to uniquely identify the records in the table and prevent insertion of duplicate values.

Let's create a dummy table:

```
create table scratchpad.test_1
(id bigint identity(1,1),
name varchar(10));

insert into scratchpad.test_1(name)
values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');

select * from scratchpad.test_1;
```

[image]

The `id` column acts as a `primary key`. Deleting any record from the table does not impact the sequencing of other values and the id column can be used to uniquely identify the subsequent row.

[image]