# pandas.to_sql write to redshift fails with NotSupportedError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am using sqlalchemy(sqlalchemy-redshift) as engine with pandas, while writing to redshift with `to_sql` i get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.NotSupportedError) SQL command "CREATE INDEX ix_western_union_answer_pivot_index ON western_union_answer_pivot (index)" not supported on Redshift tables.
 [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX ix_western_union_answer_pivot_index ON western_union_answer_pivot (index)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/tw8g)
```

While i understand the problem , [How to create an Index in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088161/how-to-create-an-index-in-amazon-redshift)

I have two questions,
1. shouldn't sqlalchemy-redshift translate the `create index` to a redshift supporting `sortkey` statement? Thats the point of using ORM right?

2. As a workaround can i stop `to_sql` from creating the db index?

UPDATE:

on setting `index=False` in `to_sql`, the above issue is solved but i endup with 
`sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(256)`

Is 256 the max size in redshift? Any solution to this apart from slicing the data to 256 and losing information?

Comment: I don't know what pandas generated `CREATE TABLE` statement looks like, but in redshift you can create `VARCHAR(65536)` columns - there's no _dynamic_ string type like Postgres' `TEXT`. But also be aware that there's a performance penalty for using very large columns in Redshift.